# My site showing a blank homepage?

Tags: blank-screen

When I go to my homepage of my site (which is a sub domain for testing: example.testcre8.co.uk) it gives me a blank white page instead of displaying my homepage.

Is there something I am missing?

Thank you

Comment: Little more information: It only happens when I am logged out of my site, when i am logged in I can see the site perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to edit your preferences.  My guess is this one:

Control Panel > Admin > General Configuration:

> Is the system on? (o) Yes () No

Comment: I'm pretty sure EE puts up a "System is offline" type message if that is set to yet.

Comment: In my general settings, my "website online" check-box is checked to online

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Member Group Settings: Site Access (Can view site when it is online), ensure this is tick to Yes. In index.php change debug setting to 1 and see what error gets thrown on the screen.